# Editing fields in Experience Editor not working

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, response-headers

For carousel components, when hovering over some text fields to edit, it does not show the cursor to edit. All other component fields are editable except for this carousel field.

Using Sitecore 10. This was working before.

It shows the following error in the console:

> 1, Refused to load the script 'a js script' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
> 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not
> explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback in
> Ribbon.aspx?sc_content=core&ribbonId=""&itemId="" file

Comment: Check your CSP headers. Your error is saying a script was blocked because of a CSP header so that is your issue.

Comment: But in components other than carousel, editing is possible. there also this console error is showing.

Answer (score 1):

[Content Security Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/) (CSP) is a must-to-have HTTP response header for any website that helps to minimise XSS risks by declaring which dynamic resources are allowed to load.

Make sure that you have a `Script-src` directive for obtaining Javascript resources declared with all applicable source expressions in your config file in `httpProtocol -> customHeaders` section. More granular directives such as `script-src-elem`, `script-src-attr` etc. are also available, but for most cases the `script-src` definition should be enough.

For example:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com;
```

where:

- `'self'` allows loading resources from the same origin - scheme, host and port;
- `'unsafe-inline'` allows use of inline source elements such as style attribute, onclick, or script tag bodies;
- `'unsafe-eval'` allows unsafe dynamic code evaluation such as JavaScript `eval()`;
- `https://example-domain.com` allows loading resources from a certain domain name, from `www.google-analytics.com` in the above use case.

Full list of supported `-src` directives can be found [here](https://content-security-policy.com/#source_list).