# Experience editor does not save changes in sitecore 10

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

Experience editor throws following errors

1. in one page, it does not allow to edit the fields
2. in other pages, after editing, when clicking on save a pop up with "Changes you made may not be saved." appears.

Sitecore 10.

Comment: Add more details, are you seeing any errors in log files?

Comment: Yes, one console error saying a script is blocked by csp in exp editor/ribbon.aspx. But this script does not throw error in cd server.
Also, whenever i save  a change, only SaveItem.CheckItemLock and SaveItem.Checkrevision are called. Others are not called.

Comment: Is the same question duplicated here?
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30620/editing-fields-in-experience-editor-not-working